# How to confirm cpu steal in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have one consumer out of 48 servers that is consistently slower than all other consumer.

Its running the same code and I even manually make it process the same traffic, but I observe it to be slower than all other consumer

We suspect there is a hardware issue or cpu steal (since it is always utilizing 100% cpu while other are utilizing 50% with the same amount of traffic)

Is there a way I can confirm that there is no cpu steal happening?

Here is some output from top

```
top - 20:38:28 up 10 days,  1:57,  2 users,  load average: 31.38, 24.56, 28.36
Tasks: 443 total,   1 running, 442 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 90.5 us,  4.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  4.6 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.8 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  30871552 total, 17587808 used, 13283744 free,   286512 . buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free. 11353472 cached Mem
```

Comment: Stop the instance then start it again - don't use restart, an actual stop, then a start. That will move it to new hardware. If the performance improves then you can probably say the issue was the host.

Comment: Well, it says there is 0.0% steal.

Answer (score 1):

You probabily can change the hardware of the instance performing actions that involves a change in your instance (Ex. changing the instance type or deploying a new machine). If you stop and start the instance, you will have a small chance to use the same hardware (but is simple and can be a good test).

If you supect the problem can be in cpu steal, you can actively monitoring this parameters using the output of iostat command.

Check too, if you are using a t2 type instance, the cpu credits metric through cloudwatch.